# Create Web App Bot service using Powershell script

Tags: azure, powershell, botframework

I have created web app service on azure using powershell script .Can i create **Web app bot** using powershell script? Is there some reference document which i can refer?
I am looking to add following services

- Bot Service Registration
- Web App
- Application Insights

Answer (score 0):

Chinmay,
the Azure Powershell module documentation can be [found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.cognitiveservices/?view=azurermps-6.12.0#cognitive_services).
Unfortunately, it doesn't look like the ability to create a web app bot is included.
If you've ever created a bot manually in the Azure portal, then you know that a bot actually consists of several azure resource types like an app service, a bot service, etc. 
I would like to see the ability in powershell myself.
If you're interested, the Azure CLI tools DO support bot creation and managements. `az bot` commands are available in that toolset. Documentation can be [found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/bot?view=azure-cli-latest#az-bot-create).